# How does serialization tool skip unknown fields during deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, hessian

How does serialization tool(i.e. hessian) deserialize a class of different version with the same `serialVersionUID`? In most cases, it can skip those unknown(not found in class loader) fields and keep compatible. But last time, I tried appending a new field of `Map<String, Object>`, put some unknown object into the map, then it threw a `ClassNotFoundException`.

- **Why can't skip the map like the others?**
- Is it a problem associated with the tool's implementation or serialization mechanism?

Comment: I try it again, find that hessian transforms the unknown type  to a `Hashmap` without throwing exceptions. But for `Class<T>` instance, `Class` is a well-known type, so it starts transforming and throws a `ClassNotFoundException` since `T` is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

This would depend on the tool itself.  `serialVersionUID` is intended for use by Java's built-in serializer (`ObjectOutputStream`) which, as best I can tell from reading the Hessian source, is not used by Hessian.

For Hessian specifically, the best source I can find which mentions these kinds of changes is [this email](https://www.mail-archive.com/hessian-interest@caucho.com/msg01111.html):

> At least for Hessian, it's best to think of versioning as a set of
> types  of changes that can be handled.
>
> Specifically Hessian can manage the following kinds of changes:    1)
> if you add or drop a field, the side that doesn't understand the
> field will ignore it.    2) some field type changes are possible, if
> Hessian can convert (e.g.  int to long)    3) there's some flexibility
> on map(bean) types, depending on how much  information Hessian has
> (which is a reason to prefer concrete types.)
>
> So, if the sender sends an untyped map {"field1", 10} and the target
> is  known to be MyValue { int field1; }, then Hessian can map the
> fields.
>
> But it cannot manage things like:    1) field name changes (the data
> will be dropped).    2) class name changes where the target is
> underdefined, like Object  field1. If you send a MyValue2 as the new
> field1, when the previous  version was MyValue1, Hessian can't make
> that automatic transition. (But  as with #3 above, a "MyValue2 field1"
> would give Hessian enough  information to translate.)    3) class
> splits, e.g. creating a subclass and pushing some fields  into it.
> 4) map to list or list to map changes.

Basically, I don't think Hessian intends to support unknown types in maps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the answer doesn't mention why it can't skip the `Map` field since it matches case 1) ?

Comment: An item in a map is not a field in Java.  Case one is specifically talking about instances of a "type".  A "type" in Hessian is a Class in Java.  So case 1 would only apply to unknown fields.  A HashMap in Java is an "untyped map" in Hessian terminology.