# Hessian (Java) deserialization of class which is not in the classpath does not raise an error

Tags: java, deserialization, hessian

Is there a way to cause Hessian deserialization to throw an exception if a class is missing on the classpath?

In [How does serialization tool skip unknown fields during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813683/) a comment says that "hessian transforms the unknown type to a Hashmap without throwing exceptions".

This is the behaviour I am watching, and which led to an error when the object is serialized again and sent back, because the type is now a HashMap.